# Push HashMap Values Into Firebase Under The Same Node

Tags: firebase, loops, hashmap, iteration, sequential

I am trying to loop through a HashMap and enter the data into the same node, however the code is pushing data into new nodes.

```
    // Iterate Through HashMap
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : namePhoneMap.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();

        fbDatabaseRefPhone.push().child("name").setValue(value);
        fbDatabaseRefPhone.push().child("phone_number").setValue(key);


    }
```

Basically I want bot the name and phone number to be pushed into the same random node.  However it is pushing them into different nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#push()) always generates a new random key every time you call it.  Just call it once and provide a single set of data to write all at the same time at new DatabaseReference it returns:

```
HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("name", value)
data.put("phone_number", key);
DatabaseReference child = fbDatabaseRefPhone.push();
child.setValue(data);
```

Comment: Works fine just a semicolon after "data.put("name", value)" in the second line.  Thank you.  Also thanks for not downvoting.